# Understanding the using statement

Tags: c#, .net, using-statement

I have written two codes:

code block 1:

```
Stream dataStream;
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
{
    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
}

//Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access
using (var reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
{
    data = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

code block 2:

```
Stream dataStream;
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
{
    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

    //Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
    {
        data = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Code block 1 is throwing error: `stream is not reachable`. 
While progmatically i think both code will work same. 
I  added  using block in to whole statment in code block 2 and it's working.
 But I'm confused why is it throwing error in code block 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because post compilation (in IL), your code gets converted to the following

Code Block: 1

```
            HttpWebResponse response=null;
            Stream dataStream;
            try
            {
                response = (HttpWebResponse) req.GetResponse();
                dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            }
            finally
            {
                if(response!=null)
                    ((IDisposable)response).Dispose();
            }

            StreamReader reader = null;
            try
            {
                //DataStream is accessed AFTER response object is disposed 
                reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                data = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            finally
            {
                if(reader!=null)
                    reader.Dispose();
            }
```

Code Block: 2

```
  HttpWebResponse response=null;
            Stream dataStream;
            try
            {
                response = (HttpWebResponse) req.GetResponse();
                dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

                StreamReader reader = null;
                try
                {
                    //DataStream is accessed while response object is alive, and connected (not disposed)
                    reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                    data = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (reader != null)
                        reader.Dispose();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if(response!=null)
                    ((IDisposable)response).Dispose();
            }
```

As you can see, in CodeBlock1, you are trying to access stream which is trying to read from a Disposed (and dis-connected) HttWebResponse object.

Comment: but in the first case, we are storing the value in datastream and then disposing the  response object then why is it not accessible?

Comment: Because you are storing a reference, and if the referenced object is Disposed is closes any network connection/handles it was holding. After that, when datastream tries to pull data it fails because the source connection is closed.

Comment: But if we do the same with a simple class and storing data in it the same way it will work fine, so any thing particular with only stream class?

Comment: Yes, stream readers are lazy, and they do not read/cache any data unless explicitly asked for (Read, ReadToEnd methods). You can wrap any reader (eg: from database, website) into a Stream and then read data as and when required. The best use case is when you read a fixed number of bytes/rows at a time, process it, and then read next - that avoids having too much data in memory.

Answer (score 5):

Based upon the behavior you have specified, it would seem that when the `HttpWebResponse` is disposed, it disposes of the response stream.

Comment: but that should not happen?  Only the response object should be disposed. Am i right ?

Answer (score 2):

Rohit, the first code block is throwing error because, once you close the braces for the using clause, the object is considered as disposed. i.e. the object is left for the GC to collect. The scope of the stream in code block 1 had expired before the second using statement.

The right way to access the stream is the second code block.

Comment: Your second paragraph is correct. Your first is somewhat confusing. Disposing an object does not make it eligble for garbage collection. Disposing an object frees any unmanaged resources directly or indirectly owned by that object. An object becomes eligble for garbage collection when it is not longer reachable from any GC roots. (Simplified: It is no longer referenced by anything in your code.)

Comment: "*The scope of the stream in code block 1 had expired before the second using statement.*" - this is incorrect since `dataStream` was declared outside of first using scope. Correct answer was provided by @TrevorPilley

Answer (score 1):

the `using` block provides you easy and correct use of objects that are disposable. therefor, anything that is initialized in the `using` statement will be constidered as disposed after the `using` block, even if you declare the variable outside of the `using` statement.

[from msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx):

> As a rule, when you use an IDisposable object, you should declare and
>   instantiate it in a using statement. The using statement calls the
>   Dispose method on the object in the correct way, and (when you use it
>   as shown earlier) it also causes the object itself to go out of scope
>   as soon as Dispose is called. Within the using block, the object is
>   read-only and cannot be modified or reassigned.

Answer (score 1):

A `Stream` is not a block of data, but a way to read that data from "somewhere".
When you dispose of that response (by exiting the using-block) you break the connection to that "somewhere". This means you can't read from that stream anymore.

Your second example keeps that connection alive until you are done reading it.

Answer (score 1):

The `using` statement ensures that the scoped object has the Dispose function called on it when the execution reaches the final bracket `}` which means the HttpWebResponse object is out of scope in the second using block.

Although you have saved your stream in the `datastream` variable the stream itself has not been read and that is done when you call `ReadToEnd()`. And as the HttpWebResponse is out of scope or Disposed then you are getting the exception you received.